# almost sure Limit of independent events

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Problem:

> Let $A_n$ be independent events with $P(A_n)=\frac{1}{n}$. Let
>   $Y_{k+1}:=min\{n>Y_k: A_n\ occurs\}$, $Y_0=0$. Show: $\lim
> \inf_{n\to\infty}Y_{k+1}-Y_k \ge 2$ almost surely

Hint: You needn't show the stronger statement $Y_{k+1}-Y_k \to \infty$ for $k\to \infty$

$A_n$ occurs infinitely often by Borel-Cantelli.
Can anybody help me?
Zitrone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\liminf_{k \to \infty} \{ Y_{k + 1} - Y_k \} \geq 2$ means that the event $Y_{k + 1} - Y_k = 1$ happens only a finite number of times, or that $A_n$ happens for consecutive values of $n$ only finitely-often.  That this will be the case with probability one can be proven using the first Borel Cantelli lemma:
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} P(A_{n} \cap A_{n + 1}) &= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n (n + 1)} \\ 
&< \infty
\end{align}
and so $P( A_n \cap A_{n + 1} \,\, \text{i.o.} ) = 0$.

**Edit**:

Incidentally, if you want to prove the stronger statement $\liminf_{k \to \infty} Y_{k + 1} - Y_k = \infty$ a.s. it's not much more difficult.  We just need to look instead at the event $\cup_{k=1}^{\infty} \{A_n \cap A_{n + k} \,\, \text{i.o.} \}$.  By Boole's inequality $P(\cup_{k=1}^{\infty} \{A_n \cap A_{n + k} \,\, \text{i.o.} \}) \leq \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} P( A_n \cap A_{n + k} \,\, \text{i.o.} ) = 0$, since each term in this sum is zero using the same argument above.